# WARNING: No attribute with name 'positio' in this module, value not set in univention ucs

Tags: powershell, univention, univention-management-console, univention-corporate-server

I am trying to configure the [OpenID Connect Provider](https://www.univention.com/products/univention-app-center/app-catalog/openid-connect-provider/) in my Univention UCS server so that I can implement Implicit Login in my Angular application. After installing, as per the document, I will have to set the configuration as below.

[image]

```
udm oidc/rpservice create --set name="lmzdevopenid" --set position cn=oidc,cn=univention,$(ucr get ldap/base) --set clientid="devclient" --set clientsecret="if===2019{}" --set trusted=yes --set applicationtype=web --set redirectURI="http://localhost:3008"
```

But I am always getting an error as below when I run the above command.

```
WARNING: No attribute with name 'positio' in this module, value not set.
E: Insufficient information: The following properties are missing:
clientsecret
clientid
redirectURI
```

Have you ever worked with this OpenID Connect Provider in Univention UCS? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was the wrong documentation of the package. We should not use `--set` before we the `position` command.

**Wrong**

```
--set position cn=oidc,cn=univention,$(ucr get ldap/base)
```

**Right**

```
--position cn=oidc,cn=univention,$(ucr get ldap/base)
```

So after running with this change, the commands were executed correctly.

```
udm oidc/rpservice create --set name="lmzdevopenid" --position cn=oidc,cn=univention,$(ucr get ldap/base) --set clientid="devclient" --set clientsecret="if===2019{}" --set trusted=yes --set applicationtype=web --set redirectURI="http://localhost:3008"
```